Short story crashing landing on a planet and taking shelter in a building that had automated defenses
Trying to find this story that my dad read in the 1960s although the story may be earlier.
It's a story where a spaceship crashes and the pilot seeks refuge and finds some kind of shelter, likely offering protection from the environment. Probably akin to a hunting lodge in today's times.
He goes inside but finds there is some kind of robot or robotic defense system. He has to hide behind furniture to avoid being spotted and killed and he eventually escapes.
If anyone has any ideas would love to hear them. Many thanks.

Could be Harlan Ellison's "Life Hutch" in New  Worlds No75  (Sep 1958) and no doubt elsewhere.
The shelter has a service robot to look after it, but this has developed a fault causing it to destroy anything that moves. However its "brain" is external and located behind a wall. The hero uses his flashlight to cause a moving dot of light to appear there, so that the robot smashes through and destroys its own brain.

An animated version of this was done for "Love, Death, and Robots", if you're interested. Season 2, episode 7

@Baronet_Canid Wow I had no idea it was an adaptation! I was thinking the description was eerily similar to the episode.

Couldn't find it online but found a copy of New Worlds No 75 on ebay and bought it, fantastic read! Appreciate adding that in so I could find it.

That's where I encountered it, as a kid of ten or eleven. Sadly I can's recalll coming across it anywhere else. It deserves better.
